# boost python return same instance with make_constructor

Tags: c++, python-2.7, c++11, boost-python

I'm trying to make so this code returns the same instance in both the init function and the callback function

## test1.py

```
import test1

c = test1.C()
print 'init:', c

def func(c):
    print 'func:', c

test1.register_callback(func)
```

## test1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class C;
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<C>> v;

class C
: public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    C() {
        std::cout << "C()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~C() {
        std::cout << "~C()" << std::endl;
    }
};

boost::shared_ptr<C> create() {
    C *c = new C();
    auto ptr = boost::shared_ptr<C>(c);
    v.push_back(ptr);
    return ptr;
}

void register_callback(object func) {
    func(v[0]);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test1)
{
    class_<C, boost::shared_ptr<C>, boost::noncopyable>("C", no_init)
        .def("__init__", make_constructor(&create))
    ;

    def("register_callback", register_callback);
}
```

The output I get now is:

```
init: <test1.C object at 0x7f62181bd5d0>
func: <test1.C object at 0x7f62181c1848>
```

And what I'm trying to get is:

```
init: <test1.C object at 0x7f62181bd5d0>
func: <test1.C object at 0x7f62181bd5d0>
```

is this possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Python constructs an object, the `__init__` will be invoked with the first argument representing the object being constructed, often called `self`.  Boost.Python tries to hide this argument as much as possible, only exposing it to an [init-expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components/boost_python_init_hpp.html#high_level_components.boost_python_init_hpp.introduction.init_expressions) under certain conditions.  The callable Python object returned from [`boost::python::make_constructor()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/boost_python_make_function_hpp.html#function_invocation_and_creation.boost_python_make_function_hpp.functions) is aware of this first argument, but there are no customization points to have it forward the argument to wrapped function.  One solution is to expose a C++ function as `__init__` with `boost::python::make_function()` that accepts all of the arguments to be provided from Python, including `self`, then delegate to the functor returned from `boost::python::make_constructor()`:

```cpp
...
std::vector<boost::python::object> v;

void create(boost::python::object self)
{
  // Create a constructor object.  In this case, a lambda
  // casted to a function is being used.
  auto constructor = boost::python::make_constructor(+[]() {
    return boost::make_shared<C>();
  });

  // Invoke the constructor.
  constructor(self);

  // If construction does not throw, then store a reference to self.
  v.push_back(self);
}

...

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<C, boost::shared_ptr<C>, boost::noncopyable>(
      "C", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_function(&create))
    ;

  ...
}
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f269dbb1a6be8b3) this approach:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class C: public boost::noncopyable {};
std::vector<boost::python::object> v;

template <typename ...Args>
void create(boost::python::object self, Args&&... args)
{
  // Create a constructor object.
  auto constructor = boost::python::make_constructor(
    +[](Args&&...args) {
    return boost::make_shared<C>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  });

  // Invoke the constructor.
  constructor(self, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

  // If construction does not throw, then store a reference to self.
  v.push_back(self);
}

void register_callback(boost::python::object func)
{
  func(v[0]);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<C, boost::shared_ptr<C>, boost::noncopyable>(
      "C", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_function(&create<>))
    ;

  python::def("register_callback", &register_callback);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> c1 = example.C()
>>> print 'init:', c1
init: <example.C object at 0x7f12f425d0a8>
>>> c2 = None
>>> def func(c):
...     global c2
...     print 'func:', c
...     c2 = c
...
>>> example.register_callback(func)
func: <example.C object at 0x7f12f425d0a8>
>>> assert(c1 is c2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It already is the same `C` instance inside of the same `shared_ptr<C>`. You can easily verify this.

The issue is that you're creating two different `py::object`s based on this `shared_ptr<C>`: one from `create()` and one from `register_callback()`. Those are necessarily going to be different objects, they have nothing to do with each other.

The simple solution is to just not use `make_constructor`. Create a factory function:

```
py::object makeC() {
    C *c = new C();
    auto ptr = py::object{boost::shared_ptr<C>(c)};
    v.push_back(ptr); // store as objects, since you need them to be the same
    return ptr;
}

void register_callback(object func) {
    func(v[0]);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test1)
{
    class_<C, boost::shared_ptr<C>, boost::noncopyable>("C", no_init)
        /* actually no_init for real */
    ;

    def("makeC", makeC);
    def("register_callback", register_callback);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know its the same instance in the vector, but how do I return the same py::object for both ways?

Comment: @Markus Why do you need that?

Comment: It's for a plugin based system, plugin can create a instance in python for example c = C(); c.some_variable = 10; then another plugin gets this instance in a registered callback, if it's not the same object, the newly created some_variable is not present obviously. I had it fixed by a ugly hack, but it didn't make a clean good api, so I prefer that C() returns the same object, or rather that I can return an object, save it somewhere and reuse the same object when I do the callback, but make_constructor cannot return an py::object

Comment: @Markus So just don't use `make_constructor`.

Comment: Now your solution is no better than my previous hack, and the plugin can't do c = C(). but instead c = makeC() which is not a good API either.